# How to change the match algorithms in CLIPS

Tags: real-time, clips

I use CLIPS to develop a real-time Expert System. I know that CLIPS use Rete match algorithms as inference engine. I want to replace Rete algorithms with Leaps algorithms. I didn't find any content related in the guide book. Which source files contain the algorithms?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture manual for CLIPS 5.1 is available here: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/other/arch5-1.pdf. It's not for the most recent version of the code, but a great deal of the information is still relevant, particularly for descriptions of the source code files.

For constructing the rete network, the more important files are analysis.c, factbld.c, factgen.c, generate.c, reorder.c, and rulebld.c.

For execution, the more important files are drive.c, engine.c, factmch.c, factrete.c, incrrset.c, reteutil.c, and retract.c.